# Nginx Invalid PID number

Tags: nginx

I issued a nginx -s stop and after that I got this error when trying to reload it.

> [error]: invalid PID number "" in "/var/run/nginx.pid"

That /var/run/nginx/pid file is empty atm.

What do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

nginx -s reload is only used to tell a running nginx process to reload its config.  After a stop, you don't have a running nginx process to send a signal to.  Just run nginx (possibly with a -c /path/to/config/file)

Comment: On a stock installation of of current distributions, you will probably want to use the start script: `sudo service nginx start`

Answer (score 23):

in my case I solved this by starting the service.

sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start

The command above will start the service in Debian/Ubuntu. It will issue an error if there is any problem (like Apache listening in the same port)

After that nginx -s reload will work like a charm

Answer (score 15):

This will clear out the issue on ubuntu 16.04 and above

```
sudo service nginx stop
```

you may need to remove the pid file `nginx.pid` whose location may be defined in file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` look for line like

```
cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep pid  #  see if pid file is defined
```

this line may live in file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
pid /run/nginx.pid;  #  in file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

if pid file does exist then remove it now

```
ls -la  /var/run/nginx/pid  #  this file may live elsewhere
ls -la  /run/nginx.pid  #  on Ubuntu 16.04+
```

after the pid file has been removed lets launch nginx

```
sudo service nginx start

ps -eaf|grep nginx        #  confirm its running

sudo nginx -t && sudo nginx -s reload   #  confirm config is OK

#      typical output
#  nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
#  nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful


sudo service nginx stop   #   issue stop

ps -eaf|grep nginx        #   confirm it actually stopped
```

now sanity has been restored and you are free to launch at will

***Root Cause of this lingering pid file:*** ____________

When nginx gets launched it first sees if there exists its pid file if yes then do not let nginx launch (putatively because nginx is already running) ... during a successful launch nginx creates this pid file to block letting nginx get launched again atop existing nginx which would cause host port blockages which is bad ... system needs to block letting multiple nginx get launched simultaneously ... on a clean exit nginx will remove its pid file ... problem happens when nginx is killed violently in which case it may fail to remove its pid file in this situtation once nginx is killed if the pid file mistakenly still exits the pid file must get manually removed so a clean nginx launch can happen

Comment: I was having problems all night. I pulled the latest commit from git repo and my sites suddenly stopped working. This solved my problem. Thank you so much. If you are free when you see this comment, can you explain why this solved my problem. My site was showing 'This site can't be reached, refused to connect and err connection refused'. Now it is finally working. Thank you so much.

Comment: @saddysad I added details to explain when pid file should exist versus should not exist

Answer (score 9):

To avoid downtime with restarting nginx,

```
ps aux | grep nginx 
PID of nginx master process

echo PID > /var/run/nginx.pid
nginx -s reload
```

Comment: In case `which pgrep` is not empty, the simpler version is `pgrep 'nginx: master process' > /var/run/nginx.pid` and then run the reload.

Answer (score 8):

In the latest version(1.2.0) that I downloaded there is no "-s start" option, it will say
nginx: invalid option: "-s start"

You can start nginx by

```
sudo /etc/nginx/sbin/nginx
```

The server will be started and then there wont be any Invalid pid number errors.

Answer (score 6):

In my case nginx was stopped (crashed I assume). Solved the issue by:

```
service nginx status
nginx stop/waiting

service nginx start
nginx start/running, process 3535
```

Then nginx -s reload worked like a charm.

I am using nginx/1.8.0 on trusty.

Comment: It is very strange how nginx documentation does not include these commands. The just say "To start nginx, run the executable file."!!
I don't know why they didn't include the line : 
**sudo service nginx start**  <-- this worked from me

Answer (score 2):

This happens if the `nginx` process was stopped manually or was killed.

Check if the process is still running:

```
sudo lsof -nP -iTCP:<port> | grep LISTEN
```

I am on mac, and I reinstall the nginx with:

```
brew reinstall nginx
```

Then start the service using brew:

```
brew services start nginx
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker Alpine users should use

`nginx`

by using that nginx will be start

check if there is no error by

`nginx -t`

> nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
>
> nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

then reload it by

`nginx -s reload`

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS 7 I done it with this:

```
 sudo systemctl start nginx
 #Then check all things are OK
 sudo systemctl status -l nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still has issues, in my case, there was an apache2 server that was running.
You can try debugging what went wrong in your nginx machine by executing this command -
`systemctl status nginx`
This gave me an insight that the port was already in us by apache2 server.
so you can do `sudo service apache2 stop` and then do `sudo service nginx start`.